# In Github, I want to prevent members from merging a pull request

Tags: git, github, pull-request

In my workflow I have two default branches: `master` (production) and `dev` (staging). All members create their branches from the `dev` branch. However, I want require the members to do a `pull request` to merge back into the `dev` branch. Additionally, I want to prevent those members from approving the `pull request`. I want to be the only one to approve a `pull request` merge after a code review.

I've been looking at [protecting branches](https://help.github.com/articles/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests/) but I'm not sure if I'm on the right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you enable branch restrictions on your `master` and `dev` as mentioned https://help.github.com/articles/enabling-branch-restrictions/, everyone who branches out from these 2 will have to create a pull request which only you can merge